# Zend framework sub query for update and select

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I want to select all prices to show and next I want to update all price. I can write sub query in MySQL but how Can I do this in zend framework query style?

MySQL query is

```
SELECT price FROM mag1.catalog_product_option_type_price where option_type_id in 
(SELECT option_type_id FROM mag1.catalog_product_option_type_value where option_id in 
(SELECT option_id FROM mag1.catalog_product_option where product_id= 11));
```

Answer (score 0):

To write your query exactly :

```
$select1 = new Select();
$select1->from('catalog_product_option')
->columns('option_id')
->where(array('product_id' => 11));

$where2 = new Where();
$select2 = new Select();
$select2->from('catalog_product_option_type_value')
->columns('option_type_id')
->where($where2->in('option_id', $select1);

$where = new Where();
$select = new Select();
$select->from('catalog_product_option_type_price')
->columns('price')
->where($where->in('option_type_id', $select2);
```

But why not try

```
$select = new Select();
$select->from(array('p' => 'catalog_product_option_type_price'))
->join(array('v' => 'catalog_product_option_type_value'), 'p.option_type_id = v.option_type_id', array())
->join(array('o' => 'catalog_product_option'), 'v.option_id = o.option_id', array())
->columns('price')
->where(array('o.product_id' => 11));
```

This should give the same result.